# Is using screen unlock pattern feature a good option for login on mobile web

Tags: login, mobile-web, authentication, pattern-recognition

trying to come up with way(s) to reduce the users' drop off rate on mobile login/registration on a mobile web ecommerce site.

1 method i think could work and would like to probably test would be a web version of the screen unlock pattern feature used on phones.  http://ignitersworld.com/lab/patternLock.html

Compared to passwords they are easier to remember and already being used by most users.

Is this a good idea? any limitations or potential problems with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How important is security to your system? You'll be effectively trading security strength with ease of use. There are less combinations available for unlock patterns as compared to using a password.

Most e-commerce sites send the user notifications whenever an order is submitted. So if you can make it easy for the user to cancel/stop orders in case of illegal access, it should be fine? I'm not a security expert though.